# Unable to connect to remote mongo db for 2 days

Tags: mongodb, spring-data, mlab

I am unable to connect to remote mongo database. 
I am using following spring dependencies in my pom:

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
      <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.3</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.1.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>
```

The relevant part of my db connection xml is:

```
<mongo:mongo id="mongo" host="ds059702.mongolab.com" port="59702"  />
<mongo:db-factory
        id="mongoDbFactory"
        host="ds059702.mongolab.com"
        port="59702"
        username="XXX"
        password="XXX"
        dbname="test081142"
        mongo-ref="mongo"/>
```

The version of mongo db is 2.6. 
The exception I am getting while connecting(basically reading) is

```
org.springframework.data.mongodb.UncategorizedMongoDbException: Query failed with error code 13 and error message 'not authorized for query on test081142.Entity' on server ds059702.mongolab.com:59702; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoQueryException: Query failed with error code 13 and error message 'not authorized for query on test081142.Entity' on server ds059702.mongolab.com:59702
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(MongoExceptionTranslator.java:96)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.potentiallyConvertRuntimeException(MongoTemplate.java:2011)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.executeFindMultiInternal(MongoTemplate.java:1894)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.findAll(MongoTemplate.java:1300)
at org.springhbx.common.dao.TestEntityDao.readAllRecords(TestEntityDao.java:34)
at org.springhbx.common.test.DaoTest.getAllRecords(DaoTest.java:46)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:82)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:240)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:180)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:157)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:74)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:211)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:67)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
```

Caused by: com.mongodb.MongoQueryException: Query failed with error code 13 and error message 'not authorized for query on test081142.Entity' on server ds059702.mongolab.com:59702

I need some help to find out where exactly i am making mistake. I am 100% sure the credentials are right. Unable to figure our the exact problem.

-------------------UPDATE------------------------------

I am able to connect and perform CRUD using

```
 MongoClientURI uri  = new MongoClientURI("mongodb://dbuser:XXXX@ds059702.mongolab.com:59702/test081142");
    MongoClient client = new MongoClient(uri);
    DB db = client.getDB(uri.getDatabase());
```

SO there must be some problem in my spring configuration only...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it looks like a question for [MongoLab Support](https://support.mongolab.com/anonymous_requests/new).

Comment: mongo lab is just providing the remote database support. I think I am making mistake in spring-mongo connection...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am able to connect to the remote mongo db using the following configurations:

```
<mongo:mongo-client id="mongo" host="ds059702.mongolab.com" port="59702" credentials="dbuser:XXXX@test081142" >
</mongo:mongo-client>
<mongo:db-factory
        id="mongoDbFactory"
        host="ds059702.mongolab.com"
        port="59702"
        username="dbuser"
        password="XXXX"
        dbname="test081142"
        mongo-ref="mongo" authentication-dbname="test081142"/>
```

Its no where written in the spring-data documentation that this is the required syntax for connecting to the mongo db using spring configuration. Sad to say, spring-data needs to provide more clarity on the configuration syntax.
Taking the syntax directly from [spring docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-document/docs/current/reference/html)

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
      xmlns:mongo="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo"
      xsi:schemaLocation=
      "http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo/spring-mongo-1.0.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

<!-- Default bean name is 'mongo' -->
<mongo:mongo host="localhost" port="27017"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

From the error message, it seems that "user" with which you are connecting to the database doesn't have the 'read' role.

The user would have to be granted the role via (maybe by your db-admin):

```
use reporting
db.grantRolesToUser(
    "reportsUser",
    [
      { role: "read", db: "accounts" }
    ]
)
```

Above code taken from the below link :

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/manage-users-and-roles/#grant-a-role

Comment: My current defined role for the user is :"roles": [
        {
            "role": "dbOwner",
            "db": "test081142"
        }
    ]